# write unsigned char bloomfilter to fifo in c++

Tags: c++, process, named-pipes, file-descriptor, bloom-filter

I was wondering how i could write an unsigned char* array to fifo safely. I have tried casting the array as char* but i don't think the contents are written or read safely since the results i get are not correct. The array is a bloomfilter.

What i'm trying to do is transfer the bloomfilter from the child process to the parent as is, so that the parent can have the same exact bloomfilter.

(from Wiki: *A Bloom filter is a space-efficient probabilistic data structure, that is used to test whether an element is a member of a set. False positive matches are possible, but false negatives are not – in other words, a query returns either "possibly in set" or "definitely not in set"*)

The child process has a list let's say virus list and each node has a bloomfilter. The parent process has a class for each child forked to store the bloomfilter in every virus node

Here is the code i have so far in the child process:

```
void send_bloomfilters(int write_fd, int buf_size)
{
  char buffer[5000]; // buffer used for concatination of bloomfilters
  char temp[200];

  VirusNode* current = virus_list.head;
  strcpy(buffer, (char *)&current->bf[0]); // coping the bloomfilter to buffer

  while(current != NULL) // sending all bloomfilter in one buffer like so: bf1#bf2#bf3#...
  {
    sprintf(temp, "#%s", (char *)&current->bf[0]);
    strcat(buffer,temp);
    current = current->next;
  }

  send_message(write_fd, buffer, buf_size); //finally sending the buffer to parent
}

// Sends <message> to file descriptor <fd> per <buf_size> characters
void send_message(int fd, char *message, int buf_size)
{
// writing the length of the message to be received
  int length = strlen(message);
  char buffer[10];
  memset(buffer, 0, 10);
  sprintf(buffer, "%d@", length);
  write(fd, buffer, 9); // sending the number of bytes reader is about to read

  int buffer_size = buf_size;
  char * input_write = new char[length + 1];
  strcpy(input_write,message); // coping the message we want to send
  char * str = input_write; // pointer to the array
  int bytes_written = 0, total_bytes = 0; // We might need to write less or more bytes
  buffer_size = length < buffer_size ? length : buffer_size; // than <buf_size>

  while(total_bytes < length)
  {
    str += bytes_written;      // move str pointer
    bytes_written = write(fd, str, buffer_size); //and write the next <buffer_size> characters
    total_bytes += bytes_written;  // adding them to the total amount of bytes written altogether

    if((total_bytes + buffer_size) > length)
        buffer_size = length - total_bytes; // reading exactly the amount that's left
  }
  delete [] input_write;
}
```

And here is the code for the parent process:

```
void receive_bloomfilters(Children *children_info, int num_children, int buf_size)
{
    struct pollfd filedescs[num_children];
    char * buf;
  char * bloomfilter;
 
  // while there are still monitors left to send a message
    while(children_sent_remain(m_info, num_children)) //function checks how many children are left to read from
  { 
      for (int i = 0; i < num_children; i++)
    {
        filedescs[i].fd = children_info[i].read_fd;
          filedescs[i].events = POLLIN;
      }
      if(poll(filedescs,num_children,10) < 0 ) printf("poll blocked\n");

      for (int i = 0; i < num_children; i++)
      {
            if((filedescs[i].revents & POLLIN))
      {
          if(filedescs[i].fd == children_info[i].read_fd)
        {
            buf = read_message(children_info[i].read_fd, buf_size);
          VirusNode* current = m_info[i].virus_list->head;


          bloomfilter = strtok (buf,"#");
          while (bloomfilter != NULL && current != NULL)
          {
            current->InsertBloom(bloomfilter);
            current = current->next;
            bloomfilter = strtok (NULL, "#");
          }
                  
            delete [] buf;
          m_info[i].not_sent_yet = false; // flag=false now that we read the message from <i> child
        }
        }              
      }  
    }
}

void VirusNode::InsertBloom(char* bloomfilter) {
  monitor_bloom->bf = (unsigned char*)bloomfilter;
}

// Reads a message from <fd> and returns it.
char *read_message(int read_end_fd, int buf_size)
{
  char buffer[10];
  int fifo_buffer_size = buf_size;
  read(read_end_fd, buffer, 9);
  char * tok = strtok(buffer, "@");
  int length = atoi(tok); // how many characters will be received
  char * input_read = new char[length + 1];

  char * str = input_read;
  int bytes_read = 0, total_bytes = 0; // We might need to read less or more bytes
  fifo_buffer_size = length < fifo_buffer_size ? length : fifo_buffer_size; // than <buf_size>

  while(total_bytes < length)
  {
    str += bytes_read;      // move str pointer
    bytes_read = read(read_end_fd, str, fifo_buffer_size); //and read the next <buf_size> characters
    total_bytes += bytes_read;  // adding them to the total amount of bytes read altogether

    if((total_bytes + fifo_buffer_size) > length)
        fifo_buffer_size = length - total_bytes; // reading exactly the amount that's left
  }

  input_read[length] = '\0';

  return input_read; 
}
```

I'm a begginer learning to code so any help would be much appreciated. Is there something i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `str-` function to manipulate byte buffers. They assume that strings are 0-terminated, so that won't work if you have 0-bytes in your filters.

Switch to `memcpy`, `realloc`. Or better yet - use `vector`s.

Comment: ok so you would suggest i copy the bits of each unsigned char to an array and write that to fifo ? Thanks for the answer btw!

Comment: @ScatterBrainer I don't know what is your `VirusNode`; does it have the length of the filter? Are those filters different sizes? Do you HAVE to send only one message with all filters? Or can you send separate messages, to avoid unneeded copies?

Comment: 1: Yes virusNode has the length of the filter in bytes, so the bloomfilter is crated like so: bf = new unsigned char[bytes]; 2: all bloomfilters are of the same size 3: No i can send them seperately if i want but i cant think of the way since i'm working with processes , maybe i will have to add sleep(1) here and there

Comment: @ScatterBrainer If you want to keep all in one message, you can send an array (or vector) of pointers to those filters, and have `receive_bloomfilters()` make copies, if needed. Also, if you know the size - don't use separators; for all you know `"#"` may be a valid symbol for those filters.

Comment: Oh you're right about the # part. Nice idea thank you! But i have one question since the fifos are files and we write characters on them, how can i write pointers to the file?

Comment: @ScatterBrainer sorry, I don't see any files or writes... Is it in `send_message`? Maybe you should post that code.

Comment: Yes my bad, i didn't post it because it's kind of complicated , send_message writes messages to the parent process buf_size characters, which means if we want to send "hello" and buf_size=2 we're going to write "he" then "ll" and lastly 'o'. I'm editing the question and posting both send_mesage and read_mesage and if you would like to take a look i would appreciate it very much! :)

Comment: @ScatterBrainer You have a lot of unneeded copies. Your `send_message` should take an array of pointers, then write the content to the file. You also don't need `strcpy(input_write,message)`, just write straight from `message`.